# In Perl, how to count the number of occurences of successful matches based on a condition on their absolute positions

Tags: regex, perl

Using just **one** Perl substitute or matching regular expression statement , how can we modify below code:

I need to modify the value of **$pattern** in below code in a way that the code would count the number of times a successful match is found in the string provided that the absolute position of the successful match satisfies a certain condition.

```
$pattern = "F1";  
$string = "F1234F12F1F1234F12F13";     
$count = 0;      
while ($string =~ /$pattern/g) {$count++} 
print $count;
```

As an example for the condition on absolute position, you could think of:

ABSOLUTE_POSITION IS DIVIDABLE by 5

In this case and based on the value of **$string** above, the output would be: 4.

Please note that once the code is complete, the only line changing on different conditions on absolute position of a successful match, would be the first line of the code.

Thanks for any help

Comment: F1 appears 6 times then why is the answer 4?

Comment: Actually it appears 6 times; however because the condition says "ABSOLUTE_POSITION IS DIVIDABLE by 5" the output would be 4 since it appears in positions 0, 5, 10 and 15, each of which is dividable by 5.

Comment: *ABSOLUTE_POSITION* is unclear and not a common definition from what I recall.  Furthermore, the fact that it can be more than one position does not sound anything absolute

Comment: by ABSOLUTE_POSITION here I meant the absolute position of a successful match in a string.

Comment: Homework, by any chance?

Comment: @i alarmed alien: See my response below.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the perl special variable [@LAST_MATCH_START](https://metacpan.org/pod/perlvar#LAST_MATCH_START) to get the output:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $pattern = "F1";  
my $string  = "F1234F12F1F1234F12F13";     
my $count;      
while ( $string =~ /$pattern/g ) {
    $count++ if $-[0] % 5 == 0;
} 
print $count;
```

#### Output:

```
4
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. Actually as stated in initial note, the only changeable part after the completion of the code should be the first line: <br> $pattern = "F1"; the reason for this is that $pattern is a argument to be passed to this .pl program. <br>
The way you changed the code, nothing in **$pattern** is changed. please note that after completion of your code, the only variable part of the code would be the first line based on different conditions on absolute position of a successful match.

Comment: @MoeR. Honestly you have to ask your professor to explain what he means by that coz I got absolutely no clue. May be you can edit your question to show your expected output so that I can follow better.

Comment: Honestly, this is not a homework or something. This is just  a home project for myself. I want to write the code once and just pass the various **$pattern** as a variable parameter to the program. As stated earlier, these **$pattern**s are just based on different conditions on absolute positions of successful matches and nothing else. In addition to the condition mentioned in initial post, another Valid conditions would be: ABSOLUTE_POSITION * ABSOLUTE_POSITION + 1 in a string is dividable by 7. As you see there except for absolute position there are nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few regular expression features that you can use to enforce this type of positional limitation on a pattern match.

1. Counting matches using a [code block within a regex](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#A-bit-of-magic%3a-executing-Perl-code-in-a-regular-expression).

   The following uses a boundary condition to enforce position, and then simply counts the number of times that the pattern matches using a code block within the regex.

   I wouldn't necessarily recommend this solution, but it does work for later versions of perl:

   ```
   use strict;
   use warnings;
   use re 'eval';

   my $pattern = qr{F1};  
   my $string  = "F1234F12F1F1234F12F13";     

   my $count;
   $string =~ /^(?:.{5})*$pattern(?{ $count++ })(*FAIL)/g;

   print $count, "\n";
   ```

   Outputs:

   ```
   4
   ```
2. Enforcing position using a [Conditional Expression](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Conditional-expressions) and [`pos`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pos.html)

   This is similar to the first solution because it also relies on a code block:

   ```
   my $count = () = $string =~ /(?(?{pos() % 5 != 0})(*SKIP)(*FAIL))$pattern/g;
   ```
3. Using a [Positive Lookahead Assertion](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Looking-ahead-and-looking-behind) and boundary conditions.

   The following technique uses `\G` and boundary conditions to enforce position.  The only trick to this is recognizing that we need to gobble the next group of 5 characters so we don't match twice.

   ```
   my $count = () = $string =~ m{ \G (?: .{5} )*? (?= ($pattern) ) .{5} }xg;
   ```
4. Use [Backtracking Control Verbs](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Backtracking-control-verbs) to intentionally parse the string 5 characters at a time.

   The following looks for a match to our pattern, if it doesn't see it, skips the next 5 characters.

   ```
   my $count = () = $string =~ m{ 
       (?= ($pattern) ) .{5}       # Match pattern and move 5 characters
       |
       .{5} (*SKIP)(*FAIL)         # Or just skip 5 characters.
   }xg;
   ```
5. Use [Position Information](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Position-information) after matching.

   The simplest solution is just to match the pattern at all positions, and then use positional information to filter out the matches that we don't want:

   ```
   my $count;
   while ( $string =~ /$pattern/g ) {
       $count++ if $-[0] % 5 == 0;
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks @Miller and appreciate your code. It definitely helps in the situation where the absolute position of a successful match in a string is dividable by 5; however if I were to change the condition, let's say, ABSOLUTE_POSITION * ABSOLUTE_POSITION + 1 in a string is dividable by 7, I would need to change the logic in your code whereas the only dynamic part should be in the line where you define the **$pattern**. This value is an argument passed to this perl program.