# Pattern matching in perl (Lookahead and Condition on word Index)

Tags: regex, perl, pattern-matching, regex-lookarounds

I have a long string, containing alphabetic words and each delimited by one single character ";" . The whole string also starts and ends with a ";" .

How do I count the number of occurrences of a pattern (started with ";") if index of a success match is divisible by 5.

Example:

```
$String = ";the;fox;jumped;over;the;dog;the;duck;and;the;frog;"
$Pattern = ";the(?=;f)"
```

OUTPUT: 1

Since:

Note 1: In above case, the $Pattern `;the(?=;f)` exists as the 1st and 10th words in the `$String`; however; the output result would be 1, since only the index of second match (10) is divisible by 5.

Note 2: Every word delimited by ";" counts toward the index set.

```
Index of the = 1  -> this does not match since 1 is not divisible by 5
Index of fox = 2
Index of jumped = 3
Index of over = 4
Index of the = 5  -> this does not match since the next word (dog) starts with "d" not "f"    
Index of dog = 6
Index of the = 7  -> this does not match since 7 is not divisible by 5
Index of duck = 8
Index of and = 9
Index of the = 10 -> this does match since 10 is divisible by 5 and the next word (frog) starts with "f"
Index of frog = 11
```

If possible, I am wondering if there is a way to do this with a single pattern matching without using list or array as the $String is extremely long.

Comment: You are expecting too much out of regex. Just use the normal approach. It will save the sanity of the one who has to maintain your code.

Comment: You should add another `the;fish` to showcase that you are looking for indices divisible by 5. For indices *not* divisible by 5 the "output" would be the same.

Comment: is your pattern fixed? I could come up with a solution that doesn't involve your pattern. You only stated you want the count. So you aren't using `pos` or any capture groups and `${^MATCH}` or the like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Use Backtracking control verbs to process the string 5 words at a time

One solution is to add a boundary condition that the pattern is preceded by 4 other words.

Then setup an alteration so that if your pattern is not matched, the 5th word is gobbled and then skipped using [backtracking control verbs](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Special-Backtracking-Control-Verbs).

The following demonstrates:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $string  = ";the;fox;jumped;over;the;dog;the;duck;and;the;frog;";
my $pattern = qr{;the(?=;f)};

my @matches = $string =~ m{
    (?: ;[^;]* ){4}       # Preceded by 4 words
    (
        $pattern          # Match Pattern
    |
        ;(*SKIP)(*FAIL)   # Or consume 5th word and skip to next part of string.
    )
}xg;

print "Number of Matches = " . @matches . "\n";
```

Outputs:

```
Number of Matches = 1
```

<kbd>[Live Demo](http://ideone.com/JT8vRo)</kbd>

#### Supplemental Example using Numbers 1 through 100 in words

For additional testing, the following constructs a string of all numbers in word format from 1 to 100 using [`Lingua::EN::Numbers`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Lingua::EN::Numbers).

For the pattern it looks for a number that's a single word with the next number that begins with the letter S.

```
use Lingua::EN::Numbers qw(num2en);

my $string  = ';' . join( ';', map { num2en($_) } ( 1 .. 100 ) ) . ';';
my $pattern = qr{;\w+(?=;s)};

my @matches = $string =~ m{(?:;[^;]*){4}($pattern|;(*SKIP)(*FAIL))}g;

print "@matches\n";
```

Outputs:

```
;five ;fifteen ;sixty ;seventy
```

#### Reference for more techniques

The following question from last month is a very similar problem.  However, I provided 5 different solutions in addition to the one demonstrated here:

- [In Perl, how to count the number of occurences of successful matches based on a condition on their absolute positions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25679399/1733163)

Answer (score 2):

You can count the number of semicolons in each substring up to the matching [pos](http://p3rl.org/pos)ition. For a million-word string, it takes 150 seconds.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw{ say };

my $string = join ';', q(),
             map { qw( the fox jumped over the dog the duck and the frog)[int rand 11] }
             1 .. 1000;
$string .= ';';

my $pattern = qr/;the(?=;f)/;

while ($string =~ /$pattern/g) {
    my $count = substr($string, 0, pos $string) =~ tr/;//;
    say $count if 0 == $count % 5;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Revised Answer

One relatively simple way to achieve what you want is  by replacing the delimiters in the original text that occur on a 5-word-index boundary:

```perl
$text =~ s/;/state $idx++ % 5 ? ',' : ';'/eg;
```

Now you just need to trivially adjust your `$pattern` to look for `;the,f` instead of `;the;f`. You can use the `=()=` pseudo-operator to return the count:

```perl
my $count =()= $text =~ /;the(?=,f)/g;
```

Original answer after the break. (Thanks to @choroba for pointing out the correct interpretation of the question.)

---

### Character-Based Answer

This uses the `/g` regex modifier in combination with `pos()` to look at matching words. For illustration, I print out *all* matches (not just those on 5-character boundaries), but I print `(match)` beside those on 5-char boundaries. The output is:

```
;the;fox;jumped;over;the;dog;the;duck;and;the;frog
^....^....^....^....^....^....^....^....^....^....
`the' @0 (match)
`the' @41
```

And the code is:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use 5.010;

my $text = ';the;fox;jumped;over;the;dog;the;duck;and;the;frog';

say $text;
say '^....^....' x 5;

my $pat = qr/;(the)(?=;f)/;
#$pat = qr/;([^;]+)/;
while ($text =~ /$pat/g) {
    my $pos = pos($text) - length($1) - 1;
    say "`$1' \@$pos". ($pos % 5 ? '' : ' (match)');
}
```

Comment: The problem is "position" doesn't count characters, but words.

Comment: Ah, yes, you++ are right. I've revised my answer with a word index approach, but left the old one in case it comes in handy.

Answer (score 1):

First of, `pos` is also possible as a left hand side expression. You could make use of the `\G` assertion in combination with `index` (since speed is of concern for you). I expanded your example to showcase that it only "matches" for divisibles of 5 (your example also allowed for indices not divisible by 5 to be `1` a solution, too). Since you only wanted the number of matches, I only used a `$count` variable and incremented. If you want something more, use the normal `if {}` clause and do something in the block.

```
my $string = ";the;fox;jumped;over;the;dog;the;duck;and;the;frog;or;the;fish";
my $pattern = qr/;the(?=;f)/;
my ($index,$count, $position) = (0,0,0);

while(0 <= ($position = index $string, ';',$position)){
  pos $string = $position++;              #add one to $position, to terminate the loop
  ++$count if (!(++$index % 5) and $string =~/\G$pattern/);
}

say $count; # says 1, not 2
```

You *could* use the experimental features of regexes to solve you problem (especially the `(?{})` blocks). Before you do, you really should read the corresponding section in the [perldocs](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Embedded-Code-Execution-Frequency).

```
my ($index, $count) = (0,0);

while ($string =~ /;               # the `;'
           (?(?{not ++$index % 5}) # if with a code condition
             the(?=;f)             # almost your pattern, but we'll have to count 
           |(*FAIL))               # else fail
          /gx) {
  $count++;
}
```